# columnType JSON > field is null cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a column in my database table (using mariaDB, where JSON is an alias for LONGTEXT) that contains JSON data in text format.

```
Articles table columns:
id (primary key) | settings
1                |  {"foo-bar": 12345}
```

When I request this row in Articles controller and debug

```
$article = $this->Articles->get($id);
debug($article);
```

The json column outputs *null*.

```
Getting = {"id" => 1,"settings" => null}

Expected = {"id" => 1,"settings" => ["foo-bar" => 12345]}
```

Not sure why this is happen, any thoughts?

Also, the json column type mapping is set in Articles Table:

```
use Cake\Database\Schema\TableSchema;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{

    protected function _initializeSchema(TableSchema $schema)
    {
        $schema->columnType('settings', 'json');
        return $schema;
    }

}
```

Comment: please show 1st a sample of that json string, 2nd the code where you try to read that value out of the string.

Comment: Updated question @jeff

Comment: Try to read the data as a string to make sure that you are actually retrieiving valid JSON data, also check `json_last_error()` and `json_last_error_msg()`, when decoding fails, your data would end up as `null`. And have a look at `get_class($this->Articles)` to check that it's actually an instance of the class that you expect.

Comment: @ndm thanks, i thought by debugging, I am reading the retrieved data.

Comment: Sure, but it's sent through the JSON type converter, so you don't see the original value, ie what I'm suggesting is to set the column type to `string` to check what's actually being retrieved.

Comment: I have set the settings column in the database table for Articles to TEXT type and commented out _initializeSchema method, i now get '{"id" => 1,"settings" => {"foo-bar": 12345}}', when I debug $article variable

Comment: Thanks @ndm, your recommendation worked, used json_last_error(), and found out I had a syntax issue.